# strstr always returns null

Tags: c++, c-strings, strstr

I am trying to get a substring from a `CString` using C++. For that I am using `strstr` function. But it is not working at al

```
CString str = m_sectionDataList->GetNext(pos);          
char* chToMatch = (char*)(LPCTSTR)str;          
char *match = "=";      
//char * sMatched = strstr(ch, match);
if (strstr(match, chToMatch) != NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, str, L"Done", 1);
}
```

Comment: That you need to cast `str` is a little worrying, do you build with `UNICODE` enabled? Then `LPCTSTR` is a *wide* character string and you can't use `strstr`.

Comment: You should avoid using C-style casts.  I'm not sure whether `CString` has a conversion operator that yields LPCTSTR; but if it doesn't then your code causes undefined behaviour. Instead write `char *chToMatch = static_cast<char *>(str);`  . If that gives a compilation error then it means your code was already broken, it's just that you now ask the compiler to detect if it was broken.

Comment: And why not use [`CString::Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314323%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) instead?

Comment: consider writing `if ( -1 != str.Find(_T("=")) )` instead, or something

Answer (score 1):

You are passing arguments in the incorrect order. `strstr` expects first argument to be scanned string, and second should be a match. Right now you are searching your target string in the one byte `=` template, which will most certainly fail.

Comment: should I change the sequence like if (strstr(chToMatch, match) != NULL)  that??

Comment: Then you should check in the debugger what are you passing to the `strstr` function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found it. Need to use a macro of C++ and you will found it converted.

```
CT2A ascii(str, CP_UTF8);
```

now you can just access it using ascii.m_psz and its buffer also.